# JOOQ with Logback

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, logback, jooq

I use springBoot with JOOQ and would like to log generated SQL's.

I added slf4J to my maven dependency and log4j.xml like in 
JOOQ documenation (http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/logging/). But when jooq executes some queries, I can not see any log in my console.

I also search for this issue in google, but I couldn't find anything.
SpringBoot uses logBack, so I have logBack and slf4J in my path. 
Is it possible to use logBack for JOOQ ? I didnt any instruction on JOOQ Site about it.

Comment: `log4j.xml` is the configuration file for ... wait for it ... log4j. Did you add log4j (or the slf4j-log4j bridge) as well as your Maven dependency?

Comment: here are my mvn dependency:
`
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jOOQ's built-it [`JooqLogger`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/tools/JooqLogger.html) tries to resolve an optional logger dependency in the following order:

- If slf4j is found on the classpath, that is used
- Else, if log4j is found on the classpath, that is used
- Else, `java.util.logging` is used

So, as soon as the `JooqLogger` finds slf4j on the classpath (e.g. as a transitive dependency from spring boot), it will use that as a logging framework. This is reasonable, because slf4j can be configured to delegate to any other logging framework, including log4j and `java.util.logging`.

So, in order to enable jOOQ's debug logging via logback and Spring Boot, it is sufficient to put the following `logback.xml` file at your classpath root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="org.jooq" level="DEBUG"/>
</configuration>
```

This is now also reflected in the [jOOQ-spring-boot-example on GitHub](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-boot-example/src/main/resources/logback.xml).

Some more ideas can be found here in the Spring Boot manual:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html